# Implementing operator overloading on abstract interface in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual, pure-virtual

I'm writing a class that is an implementation of a "mathematical function".

The "mathematical quality function" can be derived from an abstract class: `QualityFunction`. It contains a `mutable double quality` that stores the scalar value of the function once evaluated, and an `eval` method that is needed to evaluate the function value and has to be implemented by every derived class, because is a pure virtual method.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::sin;
using std::cos;
using std::vector;

class MathFunction
{
protected:
    mutable double quality; // mutable keyword allows to modify quality even in const methods.
    virtual void eval(const vector<double> &x) const = 0;

public:
    virtual ~MathFunction() {}

    double &operator()()
    {
        return quality;
    }

    double &operator()(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        eval(x);
        return quality;
    }
};
```

Then every derived class from `QualityFunction` has to implement the `eval` methods, because there are many possible `QualityFunction`s. Two examples are SumSinFunction and SumCosFunction that compute the sum of `sin` and `cos` of their argument:

```
class SumSinFunction : public MathFunction
{
public:
    SumSinFunction(){};
    ~SumSinFunction() {};

protected:
    void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        quality = 0;
        for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
            quality += sin(x[i]);
    }
};

class SumCosFunction : public MathFunction
{
public:
    SumCosFunction(){};
    ~SumCosFunction() {};

protected:
    void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        quality = 0;
        for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
            quality += cos(x[i]);
    }
};
```

This hierarchy is needed because a class `Maximizer` accepts `MathFunction` objects and, repeatedly calling `eval` will find the solution as a `vector<double> x` that maximizes the overall quality.

```
class Maximizer
{
public:
    Maximizer(){}
    vector<double>  maximize(const MathFunction &f)
    {
        // do some operations to maximize it
        // and return the maximized value
        return std::vector<double>();
    }
};
```

The problem now is when I want to create linear combinations of MathFunctions by combining derived objects to create a new object that still is a `MathFunction` instance with their member variables and methods, but that stores a quality that is a linear combinations of the qualities of its components. For example, I would like to implement the `operator+` overloading on `MathFunction` to allow me to create something like this:

```
SumCosFunction cosfun;
SumSinFunction sinfun;
MathFunction m = cosfun + sinfun;
```

One first temptative is to overload the `operator+` by means of friend function

```
friend MathFunction& operator+(const MathFunction &f1, const MathFunction &f2)
{
    MathFunction *f;
    // do something
}
```

but I can't because the constructor of MathFunction is virtual! So the question is, how can I combine different objects derived from MathFunction to generate an object that can be passed as MathFunction to my `Maximizer` class?
The full code is available on coliru  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c33664066a3658b

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> x;
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        x.push_back(i);

    SumCosFunction cosfun;
    SumSinFunction sinfun;

    //MathFunction F;// = cosfun+sinfun;

    Maximizer opt;
    opt.maximize(cosfun);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you derive a class (e.g. `ContainerFunction`) from `MathFunction`? This `ContainerFunction` could store a list (e.g. `std::vector`) of `MathFunction` objects which are all executed when calling `eval`.

Comment: you can use a pimpl idiom. `MathFunction.pimpl -> MathFunctionImpl` and your math classes inherits from `MathFunctionImpl`. Then you won't have problems with operator overloading

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how you mean to use pimpl idiom?

Comment: I guess you mean *quantity* rather than *quality*?

Comment: yes, that's just a variable storing the value of the function once evaluated. The code here has been adapted from another for sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to implement (an example) pimpl idiom

`MathFunctionImpl` will be the base of all functions

```
class MathFunctionImpl
{
  protected:
    mutable double quality; // mutable keyword allows to modify quality even in const methods.

    virtual void eval(const vector<double> &x) const = 0;
  public:

    virtual ~MathFunctionImpl() {}

    double &operator()()
    { return quality; }

    double &operator()(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        eval(x);
        return quality;
    }

    virtual MathFunctionImpl* Clone() const = 0;
};
```

We can use `UnionFunciton` to expand operations between functions:

```
class UnionFunction : public MathFunctionImpl
{
  public:

    UnionFunction( MathFunctionImpl* f1, MathFunctionImpl* f2 )
      : f1(f1), f2(f2)
    { }

    ~UnionFunction()
    { delete f1; delete f2; }

  protected:

    MathFunctionImpl* f1;
    MathFunctionImpl* f2;
};
```

Now, `SumSinFunction` and `SumCosFunction` needs a few changes. I added console messages to test the code

```
class SumSinFunction : public MathFunctionImpl
{
  public:
    SumSinFunction(){}
    ~SumSinFunction() {}

  protected:
    void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
      quality = 0;
      for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
      {
        if( i>0) std::cout << "+";
        std::cout << "sin(" << x[i] << ")";
        quality += sin(x[i]);
      }
    }

    MathFunctionImpl* Clone() const
    { return new SumSinFunction; }
};

class SumCosFunction : public MathFunctionImpl
{
  public:
    SumCosFunction(){}
    ~SumCosFunction(){}

  protected:
    void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
      quality = 0;
      for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
      {
        if( i>0) std::cout << "+";
        std::cout << "cos(" << x[i] << ")";
        quality += cos(x[i]);
      }
    }

    MathFunctionImpl* Clone() const
    { return new SumCosFunction; }
};
```

And now a class to Add to functions:

```
class SumFunctions : public UnionFunction
{
  public:

    SumFunctions(MathFunctionImpl* f1, MathFunctionImpl* f2 )
      : UnionFunction(f1,f2)
    { }

    ~SumFunctions()
    { }

    void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
      std::cout << "(";
      quality = (*f1)(x);
      std::cout << "+";
      quality += (*f2)(x);
      std::cout << ")";
    }

    MathFunctionImpl* Clone() const
    { return new SumFunctions(f1->Clone(),f2->Clone()); }
};
```

Ok, we need to create a class that stores our pimpl classes:

```
class MathFunction
{
  public:

    MathFunction( MathFunctionImpl* impl )
      : impl(impl)
    { }

    ~MathFunction()
    { delete impl; }

    double &operator()()
    {
      return (*impl)();
    }

    double &operator()(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
      return (*impl)(x);
    }

    // This method can be friend
    MathFunction operator+(const MathFunction& f2) const
    {
      return MathFunction(new SumFunctions(impl->Clone(), f2.impl->Clone()));
    }

  private:
    MathFunctionImpl* impl;
};
```

And that's all. The main to test the code:

```
int main()
{
  vector<double> x;
  for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    x.push_back(i);

  MathFunction f1( new SumCosFunction );
  MathFunction f2( new SumSinFunction );
  MathFunction sum = f1 + f2;

  double value = sum(x);
  std::cout << "=" << value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's complicated but definitely what I was looking for! Thanks! In this way the `Maximizer` can accept just an istance of `MathFunction` and all the administration is done in background!

Comment: @linello you can implement a factory to simplify the creation of new functions or consider using smart pointers to reduce memory consumption

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `MathFunction` whose `eval` is computed in terms of `eval` of two other `MathFunction`s. You don't have a class that does this, so you need to define one.

```
class SumFunction : public MathFunction
{
   MathFunction *one, *two;
  public:
   SumFunction (MathFunction* one, MathFunction* two) 
     : one(one), two(two) {}
   void eval(const vector<double> &x) const
   {
     one->eval();
     two->eval();
     quality = (*one)() + (*two)(); // is this ever correct?
   }
};
```

As a side note, I think your design would benefit greatly from making `eval` return a computed quality value and throwing away `operator()` and possibly `quality`. Also, in real code you probably want to use `std::shared_ptr` and not raw pointers.

Comment: By making `eval` returing a computed value, I loose efficiency, because sometimes that solver has just to grab the already computed value without evaluation.

Comment: By doing it your way you lose correctness becsuse you don't know if eval on your function was called from elsewhere with a different argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a different design based on `std::function`.

```
typedef std::function<double (std::vector<double> const&)> MathFunction;

MathFunction sum(MathFunction f1, MathFunction f2)
{
     return [f1,f2](std::vector<double> const& x) {
          return f1(x) + f2(x); 
     };
}
```

You can use template-method or strategy design patterns to simplify the definition of individual functions, or you write a generic function which uses a `std::function<double (double)>`, or use a template parameter. I will stick to your original example.

```
class SumCosFunction
{
public:

    double operator()(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        if (!quality) {
            *quality = 0;
            for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
                *quality += cos(x[i]);
        }
        return *quality;
    }

private:
    mutable std::experimental::optional<double> quality;
};

class SumSinFunction
{
public:

    double operator()(const vector<double> &x) const
    {
        if (!quality) {
            *quality = 0;
            for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
                *quality += sin(x[i]);
        }
        return *quality;
    }

private:
    mutable std::experimental::optional<double> quality;
};


Combining both functions is simple:

auto consSin = sum( SumCosFunction{}, SumSinFunction{} );
```